# Animating an image in JS using a randomized slope

Tags: javascript, animation

I am working on making a minesweeper bullet hell game, I want to have new bullets appear each frame, and each bullet to move according to their assigned slope value each frame. All the code works except for the start animation function, you can comment it out and then things work fine, there are just no animations.

```
//Generate the table for the game
function createTable(difficulty, mineArray)
{
document.getElementById("buttons").style.visibility="hidden";
var time = 0.00;
var row = 0;
var size = 0;
var Lives = 0;
var column = 0;
var input = "";
var completion = 0;
var minesLeft = 0;

if(difficulty == 0)
    {
        Lives = 5;
        size = 600;
        row = 30;
        column = 20;
    }
else if (difficulty == 1)
    {
        Lives = 3;
        size = 600;
        row = 30;
        column = 20;
    }
else if (difficulty == 2)
    {
        Lives = 5;
        size = 1000;
        row = 40;
        column = 25;
    }
else if (difficulty == 3)
    {
        Lives = 3
        size = 1000;
        row = 40;
        column = 25;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (mineArray[i] == 9)
            {
                minesLeft = minesLeft + 1;
            }     
    }
var head = document.getElementById("header").style.width = "100%"
document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + Lives;
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Minesweeper Bullet Hell";
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time: " + time;
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = "Mines Left: " + minesLeft;
var main = document.getElementById("main");
main.style.width = "100%"
main.style.height = "100%"
var div = document.getElementById("Table");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = "5%";
div.style.top = "5%";
div.style.right = "5%";
div.style.height = "90%";
div.style.width = "90%";
div.style.zIndex="1";
//Iterate through columns
while(completion < size)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < column; i++)
            {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                //Iterate through rows
                    for(var j = 0; j < row; j++)
                        {
                            var place = completion;
                            var td = document.createElement('td');
                            if (size == 600)
                                {
                                    td.style.width = "2%";
                                    td.style.height = "2%";
                                    td.style.color = "blue";
                                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                                    img.src = "grey square.png";
                                    img.height = "100%";
                                    img.width = "100%";
                                    td.appendChild(img);
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    td.style.width = "2%";
                                    td.style.height = "2%";
                                    td.style.color = "blue";
                                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                                    img.src = "grey square.png";
                                    img.height = "100%";
                                    img.width = "100%";
                                    td.appendChild(img);
                                }
                            if (mineArray[completion] == 9)
                                {
                                    td.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
                                    td.style.color = "red";
                                }
                            td.style.border = "1px solid #666666"
                            td.style.textAlign = "center"

                            tr.appendChild(td);

                            completion++;
                        }
                //Think about adding an event listener instead of overlaying buttons?
                main.appendChild(tr);
            }
            var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var j = 0; i < row; j++)
                {
                    cells[j].addEventListener("click", function () {    
                    //show number
                    var thiscol = this.cellIndex;
                    var thisrow = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
                    console.log("Clicked at " + thisrow + thiscol);
                    var cell = main.rows[thisrow].cells[thiscol];
                    cell.innerHTML = mineArray[(thisrow * row) + thiscol];
                    })
                }
    }
setTimeout(function(){bullets(difficulty)}, 100);
}
function bullets(difficulty)
{
//randomly generate bullets including starting positions, direction, and trajectory
//Generate starting position
//Generate starting edge
var xpos;
var ypos;
var bullets;
var slopes
var edge = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1)
var bullet = document.createElement('img')
bullet.src = "blank.png"
bullet.style.position = "absolute"
switch (edge)
    {
    //left edge
        case 1:
            bullet.style.position.left = 0 + "px";
            ypos = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            bullet.style.position.top = ypos + "px";
            bullet.id = "left";
            break;
    //top edge
        case 2:
            bullet.style.position.top = 0 + "px";
            xpos = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            bullet.style.position.right = xpos + "px";
            bullet.id = "top"
            break;
    //right edge
        case 3:
            bullet.style.position.right = 0 + "px";
            ypos = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            bullet.style.position.top = ypos + "px";
            bullet.id = "right";
            break;
    //bottom edge
        case 4:
            bullet.style.position.bottom = 0 + "px";
            xpos = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            bullet.style.position.right = xpos + "px";
            bullet.id = "bottom";
            break;
    }
//Get the slope
var xslope = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 5);
var yslope = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 5);
bullets.append(bullet);
slopes.append(xpos);
slopes.append(ypos);
startAnimation(slopes, bullets);
}

function startAnimation(var slopes, var bullets)
{
var j = 0;
var posy;
var posx;
for(i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
    {
        while(j < (j+2))
            {
                switch (bullets(i).id)
                    {
                        case "left":
                            posx = bullets(i).style.position.left;
                            posy = bullets(i).style.position.top;
                            bullets(i).style.position.left = posx + slopes(j) + "px";
                            bullets(i).style.position.top = posy + slopes(j+1) + "px";
                            break;
                        case "top":
                            posx = bullets(i).style.position.left;
                            posy = bullets(i).style.position.top;
                            bullets(i).style.position.left = posx + slopes(j) + "px";
                            bullets(i).style.position.top = posy + slopes(j+1) + "px";
                            break;
                        case "right":
                            posx = bullets(i).style.position.right;
                            posy = bullets(i).style.position.top;
                            bullets(i).style.position.right = posx + slopes(j) + "px";
                            bullets(i).style.position.top = posy + slopes(j+1) + "px";
                            break;
                        case "bottom":
                            posx = bullets(i).style.position.left;
                            posy = bullets(i).style.position.bottom;
                            bullets(i).style.position.left = posx + slopes(j) + "px";
                            bullets(i).style.position.bottom = posy + slopes(j+1) + "px";
                            break;
                    }
                j += 2;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: for some reason the animations are not running and the table isn't even created when I try to run my startAnimation function. I want to know how I can randomly generate a "bullet" every tenth of a second and have it move across the screen at a randomly generated slope.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks